# Gotra-Pravaras-Sutra-Shakha

Tags: vedas, history, tradition, vedic-rituals

I am looking to ascertain my Gotra-Pravaras-Sutra-Shakha. 
All that I know is, my name is Utkarsh Sharma. I read in my grandfather's diary, our gotra is Srivatsa.

That's all.

Now through a Google search, I have got to know my Pravaras. Which are Srivatsa: Bhargava,Syaavana,AApnavaana,Owrva,Jaamadaghnya.

Please assist me further to know my Sutra and Shakha.

Comment: There may be books of surnames and gotras by caste . Look for those. Also you may not be able to just adopt the sutra etc. of a South Indian because while apastamba is the sutra for SIs , it may be different for North Indians. It is also not necessary that all Srivastasa gotris have read the same veda over generations. So, please do some research on your genealogy and ask elders of your lineage. And look for those books I mentioned. We do have those in the South.

Comment: The following link may help to determine Shakya: http://koradeeyam.blogspot.in/2015/03/koradeeyam-knowledge-dissemination.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an [Abhivaadaye shloka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhivadaye) that is taught to you during your `Bhrahmopadesam` ? That will explain all that you are looking for.

That typically has the form:

`Abhivaadaye shri <pravaras here> trayaarsheya-pravraanvitaaha <gotram here> gotrah <sutram here> sutrah <veda here>-shaakadhyaayii shri <name> sharma naama ahamasmi`

For me,

```
pravarah: bhaargava veethihavya sahavedasa (trayaarsheya meaning three rishis)
sutra: aapastamba
shaaka: yajur
```

Comment: What is Bramhopadesham you mean during the Upanayana ceremony?

Comment: @Yogi yes the same.

Answer (score 2):

1.ok let me explain from starting "Brahmaji" have 7 childs named 'vishvamitra,jamadagni,gautam, atri, bharadvaj, vashistha, kashyapa" all the hindus or all the mankind is children of one of this 7 rishis. for exp. i am a brahman my gautra is "Vashistha".so each and every hindu is son of this rishis.

2.now the brahmin is the community which follows the vedas. so every brahmin cast have a ved. a ved named yajurveda. the two most commen branches of that veda is shukla & krishna. so the the two branches call "shakha" for exp my shakha is "shuklayajurveda".

3.what is pravara i dont know but my shakha is 3. "tree-pravaran-vita"

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.